# Difference between UuidCreate and CoCreateGuid

Tags: c++, winapi, uuid

Is there a difference between the UUIDs created by calling [UuidCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreate) and [CoCreateGuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateguid) from the Win32 API?

The documentation says CoCreateGuid just calls UuidCreate, but the remarks in the documentation are quite different.
Only CoCreateGuid specifically mentions the use case:

> [...] absolutely unique number that you will use as a persistent identifier in a distributed environment.

While Uuidcreate is instead focused on explaining the non-traceability:

> [...] generates a UUID that cannot be traced to the ethernet address of the computer on which it was generated. It also cannot be associated with other UUIDs created on the same computer.

I assume the difference might just be historic, the doc mentions UuidCreate was changed from MAC-based version 1 UUIDs to random non-traceable version 4 some time in the past for security reasons. UuidCreateSequential was introduced if MAC based UUIDs are needed.

If so, the return values of UuidCreate (RPC_S_OK, RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY, RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS) are nowadays just included for legacy compatibility, and basically obsolete?

Does anyone know more about this? As far as I can tell, there is no difference.

Comment: *CoCreateGuid just calls UuidCreate* - so this is the same, except return value on error (very unlikelly)

Comment: That's an interesting question. The only difference I could envision is that `CoCreateGuid` would subscribe the `RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY` success code to an `HRESULT` error. The documentation is vague, but that would be required to meet the *"absolutely unique number"* promise. @rbm Could you look into the implementation of `CoCreateGuid` to see what it does in addition to calling `UuidCreate` (if anything)?

Comment: @IInspectable by fact implementation is next - https://i.imgur.com/WP1V214.png if translate to c - https://pastebin.com/Y5x3ejj3

Comment: That's odd, entirely not what I expected. So `CoCreateGuid` calls `UuidCreate` and maps all success codes (other than `RPC_S_OK` and `RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY`) to an error `HRESULT`. I'm curious why `RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY` made it into the success arm of the `switch` statement, while `RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS` didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CoCreateGuid** calls **UuidCreate**.

`UuidCreate` used to be the only function, and it was a **type 1** (mac + datetime) uuid.

Later, after a kid was arrested after software he wrote was [traced back to his laptop because of his MAC address](https://www.zdnet.com/article/tracking-melissas-alter-egos/), Windows Vista changed `UuidCreate` to be a **type 4** (random) uuid.

And Microsoft added `UuidCreateSequential` as the legacy **type 1** uuid.

> For security reasons, [**UuidCreate**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreate) was modified so that it no longer uses a machine's MAC address to generate UUIDs. **[UuidCreateSequential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreatesequential)** was introduced to allow creation of [UUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/rpcdce/ns-rpcdce-uuid)s using the MAC address of a machine's Ethernet card.

Comment: This seems odd for MS as this is technically a breaking change as type 1 and 4 are different. Type 4 are technically not guaranteed unique globally. I'm guessing that MS balanced the odds of the collision with the security and made the change.

Comment: @Mgetz Type 1 UUIDs have a similar problem; in the age of machines, especially virtual machines, where people override MAC addresses and close configurations. But in reality: UUID type 4 is going to be unique throughout the universe. The real breaking change is that we liked sequential type 1 UUIDs as database primary keys. Now that they're random: page spits and fragmentation are a real problem. Hence the truly sequential UUIDs created by Entity Framework and the type [type 6 uuid](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format)

Comment: That seems like important information to translate into your answer .

Comment: @Mgetz That is all in the documentation. Anyone asking about UUIDs already knows the difference. The missing piece for him is the knowledge of the existence of `UuidCreateSequential`.